# How to upgrade postgrsql version from 9.6.5 to 9.6.14 on Centos 7.4

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6, centos7.6

I have problem with restoring databases from backup because backup was created on the 9.6.14 pg_restore's version. When I want to restore my databases on the another host (with the 9.6.5 postgres version), I get this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header
```

Backups was created with `Fc` flag so I have to use pg_restore tool to restore it.  So I decided to upgrade my postgres version to 9.6.14 on my centos 7 but I do not know how to do it. How do I download and install 9.6.14 rpm?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the PGDG packages, that should be as simple as

```
yum update postgresql96
```

You should update all installed PostgreSQL packages in this fashion.